# Ошибка при подключении sass ко vue (Syntax Error: SassError: An @import loop has been found). Как исправить?

Tags: vue.js, scss

Пытаюсь подключить sass к проекту vue. Выходит такая ошибка. Никак не могу понять. В чем ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой vue.config.js

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main.js

[image: http://joxi.ru/DrlLKjPHGDDx0r]

styles.scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот проект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А 2 раза подключение scss файла `styles` зачем?

Comment: так, это в каком месте?

Comment: Ну Вы в конфиге импортите и ещё отдельно в main.js

Comment: И что в `variables.scss`? Если Вы туда ещё подключили `styles.scss`, то так делать не надо)